# Xamarin on Visual Studio deploy Android App without debugging

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

i have a Forms Project.
My Android subproject suddenly successfully deploy on reald Android device but debug doesn't start (app starts without debugging attached to visual studio).
Last Visual Studio 2015 console message says:

> Deploy successfully on Motorola Nexus 6

Anybody can help me please?
Maybe i lost/changed something in Android Project properties?

Thanks,
Lewix

Comment: Make sure you are "Debugging" your project and aren't just running it. The `Debug -> Start Debugging` option and not the `Debug -> Start Without Debugging` option.

Comment: Yes i always choose "Start Debugging" (or F5 key)

Comment: Searching on the web, people suggest to check the debugger is xamarin and not microsoft, but i can't find this option on Visual Studio

Comment: Maybe you set your project on Release mode.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the adb server and Turn off fast deployment on visual studio and try it.

=> Project / Project Options / Android Build / Fast deployment

Comment: I did these steps: clean whole solution, removed fast deployment, rebuild xamarin.droid project but nothing changed, app is deployed on device (and it starts) but debug doesn't work

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617687/visual-studio-cant-debug-android-xamarin-app

Comment: I did a new xamarin project, copied all source files into it and i added this project to forms solution. Everything works. Maybe cache project data was corrupted in previous project.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Xamarin, but you can deploy a Cordova app to a device with or without debugging by using the default Visual Studio shortcuts "F5 - Start Debugging" and "CTRL+F5 - Start Without Debugging".

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me too; maybe you forgot to set a launcher activity 
 [Activity(Label = "yourAppName", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]