# Visual studio is not debuging Xamarin.Android app

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

Referring to the question, i know this question is already been posted and following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32617763/6856823) i have done what's the answer is given but still i am unable to debug my application

Bellow is the image that shows that i have set my debugging option to `Microsoft`

[image]

Please see the red boxes and tell me what's i am missing. Also i have run my application on different emulator as well as on my device but still debugging won't start

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

My debugger is set to Xamarin and not Microsoft, does that help you ?

Comment: Yes in your image the debugger is set to Microsoft.... so try and change it

Comment: By default it was set to Xamarin but still debugging didn't start